# Body parser returning undefined for req.body request (SIMPLE LOGIN for beginner)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

So I installed body parser via

```
npm i install express body-parser
```

and I wrote a simple code designed to input a user into an array after they complete a registration form.
but when I console.log the user it returns undefined for both email and password

here is the server code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const PORT = 3000;



var Users = [{"email":"mike@gmail.com", "password":"456"}];


app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('index.ejs')

})


app.get('/Register.ejs', (req, res) => {

    res.render('Register.ejs')

})

app.post('/views/Register.ejs', (req, res) => 
{

const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
};
Users.push(newUser);

res.json(req.body.email);
console.log(Users)
}
)


app.listen(PORT);
```

here is the html for the register page

```
<h1>Please Register</h1>
<body>
    <form action="/views/Register.ejs" method="POST">
        <div class="div">
        <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email"for="email" id="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="div">
        <label for="password">Enter new password</label>
        <input type="password" for="password" id="password" required>
        </div>
    
        <button type="submit"> Register </button>
        </form>





</body>
```

Comment: You need to set your  `input ` tags with a  `name ` attribute. This is the value for this attribute that will end up being parsed into a property name on  `req.body `.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only installing body-parser is not enough. You have to put them in the code as middleware.
Top of the code use:
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
and then use the code in somewhere middle of the code:
app.use(bodyParser.json())

Comment: See these resources I am providing, here you can get a clear idea of what to do with body-parser, and don't forget to install cors and use it as middleware...for 
 body-parser:https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser       and for cors:https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors